# check box if equal to value retrieved from database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm developing a website where students can subscribe to certain hours they have to attend, and each hour has an unique ID (pitid), the code below searches for the hours the user subscribed itself to, and I want the checkbox to be checked if the pitid is equal to a value retrieved with the code below. But i can't figure out how; maybe put the query result in an array and check for each pitid if it's equal to one of the values saved in the array...

!(http://i63.tinypic.com/14uj77k.png)

```
$user=$_SESSION['user'];
$q=mysql_query("SELECT timetable.pitid FROM timetable,hours WHERE llnr='".$user."' AND timetable.pitid=hours.pitid AND hours.location='olc' ");

for($i=0; $i<mysql_numrows($q);$i++){
    $check=mysql_result($q,$i,"pitid");
    echo"$check<br>";
 }
```

This is the code that generates the list:

```
$user=$_SESSION['sess_user'];
$olchours= mysql_query("SELECT pitid,pit,hour,location,seats FROM hours     WHERE `hours`.`location` = 'olc' ORDER BY pitid");
echo'<table>
        <tr>
           <td width="100px">Select</td>
           <td width="100px">PIT.ID</td><td width="100px">Day</td>
           <td width="100px">hour</td><td width="100px">taken seats</td>
           <td width="300px">Available Seats</td>
        </tr>'; 
for($i=0; $i<mysql_numrows($olchours); $i++){
    $olcpitid=mysql_result($olchours,$i,"pitid");   
    $olcday=mysql_result($olchours,$i,"pit");   
    $olchour=mysql_result($olchours,$i,"hour");
    $olcseats=mysql_result($olchours,$i,"seats");       
    $olcq=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hours,timetable WHERE hours.pitid='".$olcpitid."' AND hours.pitid=timetable.pitid");
    $olcrow=mysql_fetch_assoc($olcq);
    $olcmatches=$olcrow['COUNT(*)'];        
    $olcopen=$olcseats-$olcmatches;
        if(($i%8)==0){
            echo'<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td><form method="POST" action=""><input type="checkbox" name="hourolc[]" value="'.$olcpitid.'">
            <td>'.$olcpitid.' </td><td>'.$olcday.' </td><td>'.$olchour.'</td><td>'.$olcmatches.'</td><td>'.$olcopen.'</td></tr>';
        }               
            else{
                echo'<tr><td><form method="POST" action=""><input type="checkbox" name="hourolc[]" value="'.$olcpitid.'" >
                <td>'.$olcpitid.' </td><td>'.$olcday.' </td><td>'.$olchour.'</td><td>'.$olcmatches.'</td><td>'.$olcopen.'</td></tr>';
            }


}
echo'</table><br>';
```

}

Comment: please format your code

Comment: i tried but SO messed it up pretty bad;p

Comment: $check should be an array. You can store values in array format if you change $check to $check[] = .......
and then check  $olcpitid in $check array....hope you will get the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit your if else

```
<?php 
    if(($i%8)==0){
        echo'<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td><form method="POST" action=""><input type="checkbox" name="hourolc[]" value="'.$olcpitid.'"';if($your_db_value == $to_be_matched){echo 'checked="checked"'}echo'>
        <td>'.$olcpitid.' </td><td>'.$olcday.' </td><td>'.$olchour.'</td><td>'.$olcmatches.'</td><td>'.$olcopen.'</td></tr>';
    }               
        else{
            echo'<tr><td><form method="POST" action=""><input type="checkbox" name="hourolc[]" value="'.$olcpitid.'"';if($your_db_value == $to_be_matched){echo 'checked="checked"'} echo' >
            <td>'.$olcpitid.' </td><td>'.$olcday.' </td><td>'.$olchour.'</td><td>'.$olcmatches.'</td><td>'.$olcopen.'</td></tr>';
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: I got that working, but let's say my to be matched id's are more than 1 (i store all the values in an array that i retrieved from my database with a query), if this: $your_db_value == $to_be_matched is TRUE than the array should move on to its next value, it tried doing it like this:
    `for($p=0;$p<count($check);$p++){if($olcpitid == $p[0]){echo 'checked="checked"';}$p++;}echo'>` but that won't work...

Comment: P.S. this is how i retrieve $check:
    `$q=mysql_query("SELECT timetable.pitid FROM timetable,hours WHERE llnr='".$user."' AND timetable.pitid=hours.pitid AND hours.location='olc' "for($i=0; $i<mysql_numrows($q);$i++){
  $check[]=mysql_result($q,$i,"pitid");
   echo$check[$i];  
  }`

Comment: you are comparing   $olcpitid with $p, $p is not your array you need to compare it with $check[$p]  
`for($p=0;$p<count($check);$p++){if($olcpitid == $check[$p]){echo 'checked="checked"';}$p++;}echo'>`

Comment: ofcourse it is, overlooked it in a hurry. I got the checkbox working now, except, it only uses half of the array. The funtion now checks array[0] but not array[1] and so fort. `;for($p=0;$p<count($check);$p++){if($olcpitid == $check[$p]){echo 'checked="checked"';}$p+=1;}` i can't really come up with the place where it goes wrong...

Comment: is `$check` multidimensional array ?? what is you array format ??

Comment: sorry i found the problem already, in the for loop i said p++ and just before the for loop closes and starts over, i again said p++, so that's why it wasn't working the i wanted it to. Thanks for all the help +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Read the comments for explanation.

```
$queryResult = array('', '', ''); // list from db
$to_be_matched_pitid = 3; // to be matched pitid

if(in_array($to_be_matched_pitid, $queryResult)) {
    echo 'array CONTAINS the pitid';
} else {
    echo 'array does not CONTAIN the pitid';
}
```

Comment: Okay that helps a bit, but the actual problem i face now that i don't know how to put the results from $q=mysql_query("SELECT timetable.pitid FROM timetable,hours WHERE llnr='".$user."' AND timetable.pitid=hours.pitid AND hours.location='olc' "); in an array

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$check=mysql_result($q,$i,"pitid");
```

to

```
$check[]=mysql_result($q,$i,"pitid");
```

to store values in array

Comment: that works now, thanks! But now the last issue: I echo every row with a checkbox(every row has its unique id-> pitid) and want the checkbox of that row to be checked if the rowid(pitid) is equal to a value from the array 
This is the code that echos the row            
    
    echo'<tr><td><form method="POST" action=""><input        type="checkbox" name="hourolc[]" value="'.$olcpitid.'" >
    <td>'.$olcpitid.' </td><td>'.$olcday.' </td><td>'.$olchour.'</td> <td>'.$olcmatches.'</td><td>'.$olcopen.'</td></tr>';